# Проведение рефакторинга функций сортировки массива объектов

Tags: javascript

Есть код, позволяющий сортировать массив объектов. Надо сделать рефакторинг сортирующих функций `sortString()` и `sortDate()`, чтобы избавиться от повторяющихся фрагментов кода.

```js
const Users = [
  { id: '3', name: 'Alex', dob: '1999-01-24' },
  { id: '1', name: 'Maikl', dob: '1975-10-07' },
  { id: '2', name: 'anna', dob: '1977-06-09' },
  { id: '4', name: 'Masha', dob: '2004-10-11' },
];

const UsersSort = (function () {
  function sortNumber(param1, param3) {
    if (param3 === 'asc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    }
    if (param3 === 'desc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
    }
    return false;
  }

  function sortString(param1, param3) {
    if (param3 === 'asc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => {
        const aname = a.name.toLowerCase();
        const bname = b.name.toLowerCase();
        if (aname > bname) return 1;
        if (aname < bname) return -1;
      });
    }
    if (param3 === 'desc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => {
        const aname = a.name.toLowerCase();
        const bname = b.name.toLowerCase();
        if (aname > bname) return -1;
        if (aname < bname) return 1;
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  function sortDate(param1, param3) {
    if (param3 === 'asc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => {
        const adate = new Date(a.dob);
        const bdate = new Date(b.dob);
        return adate - bdate;
      });
    }
    if (param3 === 'desc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => {
        const adate = new Date(a.dob);
        const bdate = new Date(b.dob);
        return bdate - adate;
      });
    }
    return false;
  }

  function chengeArray(param1, param2, param3) {
    if (param2 === 'id') {
      return sortNumber(param1, param3);
    }
    if (param2 === 'name') {
      return sortString(param1, param3);
    }
    if (param2 === 'dob') {
      return sortDate(param1, param3);
    }
    return false;
  }

  return {
    users(param1, param2, param3) {
      return chengeArray(param1, param2, param3);
    },
  };
}());

console.log(UsersSort.users(Users, 'id', 'asc'));
```

Comment: Если надо, то сделайте. В чем вопрос?

Comment: @AlexDevTime орнул)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сортировку даты действительно можно убрать. Проблема вся в том, что в функции sortString вы не использовали второй параметр. Теперь осталась одна функция на две сортировки.

```js
const Users = [
  { id: '3', name: 'Alex', dob: '1999-01-24' },
  { id: '1', name: 'Maikl', dob: '1975-10-07' },
  { id: '2', name: 'anna', dob: '2004-09-01' },
  { id: '4', name: 'Masha', dob: '2004-10-11' },
];

const UsersSort = (function () {
  function sortNumber(param1, param3) {
    if (param3 === 'asc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    }
    if (param3 === 'desc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);
    }
    return false;
  }

  function sortString(param1, param2, param3) {
    if (param3 === 'asc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => {
        const aname = a[param2].toLowerCase();
        const bname = b[param2].toLowerCase();
        if (aname > bname) return 1;
        if (aname < bname) return -1;
      });
    }
    if (param3 === 'desc') {
      return param1.sort((a, b) => {
        const aname = a[param2].toLowerCase();
        const bname = b[param2].toLowerCase();
        if (aname > bname) return -1;
        if (aname < bname) return 1;
      });
    }
    return false;
  }


  function chengeArray(param1, param2, param3) {
    if (param2 === 'id') {
      return sortNumber(param1, param3);
    }
    if (param2 === 'name' || param2 === 'dob') {
      return sortString(param1, param2, param3);
    }
    return false;
  }

  return {
    users(param1, param2, param3) {
      return chengeArray(param1, param2, param3);
    },
  };
}());
console.log(UsersSort.users(Users, 'dob', 'asc'));
```

Comment: И 'chAnge' пишется через A.